# Pig Error trying Edureka's Tutorial

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-pig

I've been trying to run hadoop and other components like PIG.

I'm trying this tutorial: 
https://www.edureka.co/blog/pig-programming-create-your-first-apache-pig-script/

Everything is right, but when I run the script at step 2 it throws this error:

```
2018-01-09 13:47:20,682 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob - PigLatin:output.pig got an error while submitting 
org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/carlos/information.txt
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:279)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:318)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:196)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:335)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.submit(PigJobControl.java:128)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:194)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:276)
```

Comment: `Input path does not exist`... So, make it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior to step 1, you needed this command

```
hadoop fs –copyFromLocal /home/carlos/information.txt /carlos
```

However, this will copy your file to **a file** named `/carlos` on HDFS, if that directory doesn't already exist.

If you want `/carlos` to be a directory, you need to delete the file and make it

```
hadoop fs -rm /carlos
hadoop fs -mkdir /carlos
```

Also, trailing slashes should generally be used when copying files into a directory, like so

```
hadoop fs –copyFromLocal /home/carlos/information.txt /carlos/
```

---

You could also just make your Pig code load `/carlos` as the file. Even if it was a directory, this would still work to read all files in there

Comment: Sure you're right, but I copied the command this way hadoop fs –copyFromLocal /home/carlos/information.txt /carlos also I repeated this command and console says '/carlos file exist'

Comment: If you run `hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://localhost:9000/carlos`, do you see the file?

Comment: look what it shows, i can't see the file information.txt (sorry I'm newbie)    `-rw-r--r--   1 carlos supergroup        213 2018-01-10 10:20 hdfs://localhost:9000/carlos`